# How can I get lat long added against a key in redis GEOADD

Tags: node.js, redis

I am adding latitude and longitude of a trip in redis  server like this

```
redisClient.geoadd(tripId, [result.start_lat, result.start_long, "startLocation"], function (err, result) {
                        console.log(err, result);
                    });
```

I want to get these latitude and longitude against startLocation key. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the [`GEOPOS`](https://redis.io/commands/geopos) command for that.

```
redisClient.geopos(tripId, "startLocation"], function (err, result) { console.log(err, result); });
```